# Add Configurable Products to Bundle

Tags: magento, bundle, configurable

Is there any way to add configurable products to a bundle product in Magento? Either by way of extension or extra code.

**For example:** We have a T-Shirt that is a part of a bundle. The T-Shirt is configurable by color and size. We would like to be able to add this configurable product to the bundle product instead of adding each individual simple product that is associated with the configurable. Is this possible?

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

By default magento doesn't allow you to add configurable products to bundles, but there are custom modules that can. Check Configurable Bundle 2.0 by Wizkunde